# Refer to scope variable in directive two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a reusable progress bar directive with isolate scope. This directive will have the public functions to start, stop and reset the progress bar. This directive will be used within `ng-repeat`

Here is the definition of directive:

```
chatApp.directive('jsProgress', function() {

    var Stopwatch = function(options, updateCallback) {

         // var timer       = createTimer(),
           var   offset, clock, interval;

          // default options
          options = options || {};
          options.delay = options.delay || 1;


          // initialize
          reset();

          function start() {
            if (!interval) {
              offset   = Date.now();
              interval = setInterval(update, options.delay);
            }
          }

          function stop() {
            if (interval) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              interval = null;
            }
          }

          function reset() {
            clock = 0;
           // render(0);
          }

          function update() {
            clock += delta();
           // render();
            updateCallback();
          }

          function delta() {
            var now = Date.now(),
                d   = now - offset;

            offset = now;
            return d;
          }

          // public API
          this.start  = start;
          this.stop   = stop;
          this.reset  = reset;
          this.update = update;
        };



    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        replace : true,
        scope: { api: '=', key: '@'},
        template: '<div class="dot" ng-attr-id="dots"><ul id="{{key}}" data-currentState="2"><li class="dot-red"></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul></div>',
        link : function($scope, elem, attr) {

            var timer = new Stopwatch( {delay: 5000}, updateCallback);
            timer.start();
            function updateCallback()
            {
                var currentCount;
                currentCount = $(elem).find('#' + $scope.key).attr('data-currentState');
                currentCount++;
                $(elem).find('#' + $scope.key).attr('data-currentState',currentCount);
                $(elem).find('#' + $scope.key+' li:nth-child(' + currentCount + ')').addClass('dot-red');

            }

            $scope.api = 
            {
                    reset: function()
                    {
                        timer.reset();
                    },

                    start: function()
                    { 
                        timer.start();
                    },

                    stop: function()
                    {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                };

        }
    };
});
```

This is how it will be used within ng-repeat

`<js-progress api="{{activeUserId}}" key="{{activeUserId}}_{{activeCompanyId}}" />`

Now I want to get a particular instance of directive within ng-repeat and call its public API to start, stop and reset the particular progress bar. How can I do the same? In the above definition, it doesn't allow me to use the variable {{activeUserId}} because I want to refer each instance individually in the ng-repeat.

Comment: this could get expensive...but how many of these will you have on a page?

Comment: Not more than 15 ...

Comment: would it be easier to use watch to monitor a $parent scope object that is designated by an attribute?  That way you don't have to bother with any commands for start stop reset, etc.  You can just update the objects that store all the data for each progress bar and keep it all on the controller $scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your `activeUserId` which is being passed from your Ctrl to your directive at at this line:

```
$scope.api = {};
```

I believe that you should keep track of your api objects in your controller in this way:

in your controller

```
$scope.bars = [
    {
        activeUserId: "id",
        activeCompanyId: "companyId",
        api: {} //this allows angularjs to reuse this object instance
    },
    {
        activeUserId: "id2",
        activeCompanyId: "companyId2",
        api: {} //this allows angularjs to reuse this object instance
    },
];
```

the html template for your controller

```
<div ng-repeat="b in bars">
    <js-progress api="b.api" your-extra-params-here />
</div>
```

Later on in your controller, you will be able to do:

```
$scope.bars[0].api.start();
```